# DRC sim: IMU joint

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The current Atlas model incorporates an 'IMU joint'. We were wondering why this needs to exist. Is it just a quick way to calculate the acceleration of a given point on the robot with respect to the world?

I'm guessing from the fact that the joint limits are 0 in both directions that this joint tries to simulate a rigid connection. I'm worried however that since the mass of the attached body is quite low, the joint limit stiffness and damping can't be very high without causing instability. So my worry is that we're going to end up with an IMU that is only loosely attached to the body it tries to measure the acceleration of.

Could you try to alleviate my worries? ;-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1095/drc-sim:-imu-joint/) by [tkoolen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/64/tkoolen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The joint is fine, and the imu on ATLAS has worked properly during the virtual robotics challenge.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0